# Select only one checkbox from multiple checkbox in a row from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, datagridview

I'm using `DataGridView` with DataSource from TableAdapter and add 5 unbound columns with type `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` .

They are :  "`lima`","`empat`","`tiga`","`dua`","`satu`"

What I need to do, in the same row when checkbox "lima" is selected, the rest checkboxes become unselected or only can select one checkbox in the same row

Here's what I wrote down in `CellValueChanged` event :

```
   Private Sub DataGridView3_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellValueChanged
        If DataGridView3.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim SelectedColumnName = DataGridView3.Columns(DataGridView3.CurrentCellValue.ColumnIndex).Name

            If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView3.Columns("lima").Index OrElse _
               e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView3.Columns("empat").Index OrElse _
               e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView3.Columns("tiga").Index OrElse _
               e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView3.Columns("dua").Index OrElse _
               e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView3.Columns("satu").Index Then

                Dim Row = CType((CType(DataGridView3.DataSource.Current, DataRowView)).Row, DataRow)

                If SelectedColumnName = "lima" Then
                    If DataGridView3.CurrentRowCellValue("lima") = "True" Then
                        Row.Item("empat") = False
                        Row.Item("tiga") = False
                        Row.Item("dua") = False
                        Row.Item("satu") = False
                    End If

                   'and so..on 

                ElseIf SelectedColumnName = "satu" Then
                    If DataGridView3.CurrentRowCellValue("satu") = "True" Then
                        Row.Item("lima") = False
                        Row.Item("empat") = False
                        Row.Item("tiga") = False
                        Row.Item("dua") = False
                    End If

                End If

                DataGridView3.CurrentCell = DataGridView3(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
            End If
            End If

    End Sub
```

And this is the functions for `CurrentCell` and `CurrentRowCellValue` in module

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function CurrentRowCellValue(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnName As String) As String
    Dim Result As String = ""
    If Not sender.Rows(sender.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(ColumnName).Value Is Nothing Then
        Result = sender.Rows(sender.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(ColumnName).Value.ToString
    End If
    Return Result
End Function

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function CurrentCellValue(ByVal sender As DataGridView) As DataGridViewCell
    Return sender(sender.Columns(sender.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Index, sender.CurrentRow.Index)
End Function
```

and this is from `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event

```
Private Sub DataGridView3_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If TypeOf DataGridView3.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
        DataGridView3.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

I already set the DataGridView's ReadOnly property to False. The problem is that I still can check all the checkboxes in the same row.

[image]

Can someone give advice of what I did wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

- See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) concerning `CellValuechanged` event when working with `checkBoxs`
- If they are unbound columns, you can't change values via the `DataSource.Current` row: table has no definition for lima, empat, ...

This workaround (using `CellContentClick`) works for me (no need to extension methods and `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event):

---

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellContentClick

        Dim checkboxIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
        checkboxIndexes.Add(DataGridView3.Columns("lima").Index)
        checkboxIndexes.Add(DataGridView3.Columns("empat").Index)
        checkboxIndexes.Add(DataGridView3.Columns("tiga").Index)
        checkboxIndexes.Add(DataGridView3.Columns("dua").Index)
        checkboxIndexes.Add(DataGridView3.Columns("satu").Index)

        If checkboxIndexes.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        'check for false value because event occurs before row is validated
            If DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False Then
                For Each index In checkboxIndexes
                    If index <> e.ColumnIndex Then
                        DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(index).Value = False
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, It works this way...! Thanks for code and link reference  :)

Answer (score 0):

I made an improve to the code added before in order to achieve my goals of checking checkboxes of the same row in different columns. It works for me.

```
Private Sub Grilla_CellClick(sender As Object, e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Grilla.CellClick

    Dim checkboxIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
    checkboxIndexes.Add(Grilla.Columns("Select").Index)
    checkboxIndexes.Add(Grilla.Columns("Select1").Index)


    If checkboxIndexes.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        'check for false value because event occurs before row is validated
        If Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False Then
            For Each index In checkboxIndexes
                If index <> e.ColumnIndex Then
                    'Do nothing here
                Else
                    If Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False Then
                        Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(index).Value = True
                    Else
                        Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
                    End If

                End If
            Next

        Else

            If Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True Then
                For Each index In checkboxIndexes
                    If index <> e.ColumnIndex Then
                        'Do nothing here
                    Else
                        If Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False Then
                            Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(index).Value = True
                        Else
                            Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
                        End If

                    End If
                Next
            End If

        End If
    End If

    Grilla.TableElement.Update(GridUINotifyAction.DataChanged)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you, please, explain briefly the improvement?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn´t clear enought, i meant that i adapted it to my needs, these were to be able to check and uncheck, in this case, 2 checkboxes in the same row independently between them.

Comment: Is it an answer for the OP's question?